# Failing Unit-Test. Detailes not displayed

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am using TFS2018.3 and the recent build Agent.
if Tests fail, I don't get the Details displayed any more.
Instead I see error message:

> We can't reach the server to fetch test results. Please refresh the page to try again.

[image]

Following the advise to refresh the page does not help.
What is the cause for this Issue?

Comment: I have the exact same issue.

The problem is that /tfs/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/test results in a 500 (Internal Server Error) response.

Response Body:
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","typeName":"System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib","typeKey":"NullReferenceException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}

#NullReferenceExceptionsFTW

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found the cause. If I switch the Locale Language Settings back to German in my user profile the test results are shown correctly.

It's probably a TFS bug. Reported here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/556349/tests-tab-does-not-show-test-results.html

Comment: It's supposed to be fixed with Azure DevOps Server 2019.